# Dante enabled RaspberryPi

Tags: audio, streaming

Is it possible to make Raspberry Pi Dante enabled?
Lets asume we have a sound card on RPi like hifiberry ADC+DAC.

[For ones who wonder dante](https://www.audinate.com/meet-dante/what-is-dante)

Comment: Probably if you buy the hardware mentioned from them.

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean. Why should I buy their hardware?

Comment: Well, hardware and/or software; look at the bit from your link under "How do manufacturers get Dante for their products?".  That's how you'd enable a device, unless you find someone who's already gone through that process and sells Dante enabled Pis.   Considering the context WRT to software, there is a decent chance they'll have a version that can run on a Pi (if not you are out of luck).   But I suspect the licensing fees will make it not worthwhile for an individual project.

Comment: Do you specifically need Dante or will AES67/AES70 do what you need?

Comment: I was looking for Dante specifically but AES67/AES70 also took my attention. Do you know any combination of AES67/AES70 and RaspberryPi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! You need to specify what Dante product you mean. From the web page the products is either Windows or "We provide a ISO" that can be deployed in some virtualization platforms. And from what I have seen they don't state what standard they are using for streaming so...

Comment: This not about product I guess. Auidate is not only producer of dante devices.
If I use Hifiberry DAC+ADC I prefer to make 2 audio output 1 audio input device. Once I made RPi dante enabled, dante controler should see my RPi as 2 Out and 1 in dante enabled device.

Comment: They may not be the only producers of such products, but they are certainly the ones who [license the tech to other manufacturers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_(networking)#History).  It is proprietary, and Auidate *owns it*.  You will need to pay someone something, and in order to do that you will need to contact them.  You can leave this question here, but I suggest you pursue your inquiries with Auidate, because they are the only ones who can tell you the official truth.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, you can put most Dante Products into [AES67 mode](https://www.audinate.com/learning/faqs/aes67-interoperability). If you put an AES67 stack on your Pi than you can send and receive audio at 48 kHz and 1ms latency. So it's not full Dante capacity, but enough in most cases where a RPi is used. For the receiving case, there is an example gstreamer pipeline on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260099/). Also [pipewire](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/AES67) is working to support AES67.

If you want "native" Dante, goldilocks comment still holds. You'd have to partner with Audinate to achieve this.